# R: type of X is double but as.numeric(X) is FALSE?

Tags: r, double, numeric, typeof

I'm a new user of R, I have an object of type 'double', but when I get is.numeric(X) it returns FALSE, how is it possible? It seems to me that as X is a  list of double numbers, it should be also of type numeric. Is't it?

Here is the example:

```
student_ages <- difftime(strptime(rep("2016-05-01 00:28:15" , 3), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), strptime(rep("2015-03-01 00:28:15" , 3), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") , units="days")/365
typeof(student_ages)
[1] "double"
is.numeric(student_ages)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: `as.numeric` should not be returning logical values. Are you sure you weren't using `is.numeric`? And ... what is `class(object)`?

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo, I edited the question

Comment: Well, in R 'double' is a synonym for 'numeric' so you really do need to post a reproducible example.

Comment: @42- the example is added to the question

Comment: Still everything according to the documentation: `Factors are handled by the default method, and there are methods for classes "Date", "POSIXt" and "difftime" (all of which return false)`.

Comment: The default method for `is.numeric` returns `TRUE` if its argument is of mode "numeric". There are methods for classes `Date`, `POSIXt` and `difftime` (all of which return `FALSE`). In console, `mode(student_ages) # numeric; is.numeric(student_ages) # FALSE`. I think, the methods of difftime that causes `FALSE` should have been specified in the documentation of `is.numeric`. This would prevent misunderstandings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `dput` on the object (and this is one of the very best way to determine inner structures of R although the `str` function also serves well in many instances) .... you can see that it has class 'difftime':

```
> dput(student_ages)
structure(c(1.16974885844749, 1.16974885844749, 1.16974885844749
), units = "days", class = "difftime")
```

In R it is the `class` that determines function dispatch and function results. The `typeof` function returns a lower level piece of information. Factor vectors also return "numeric" from `typeof` but FALSE from `is.numeric()`. You could have meaningfully coerced that value to "numeric" (="double") with `as.numeric`:

```
> as.numeric(student_ages)
[1] 1.169749 1.169749 1.169749
```

Comment: So why typeof and class return two different things?(double, difftime)

Comment: Yeah I guess `as.numeric()` is more intuitive than `c()` :)

Comment: @Alex - Because one's the type and one's the class.  They are not the same function.

Comment: So when I pass an object to a function it dose type checking based on the class of the object?

Comment: @Alex: My opinion on the "why" question is that it's a simple design decision. The authors of S decided that it was the class that would be paramount in object handling but they still wanted to used numeric values to represent other types of objects.